# Craft 4 Custom Variables - From Env > General.php > template

Tags: environmentvariables, craft4

Been trying for a wee while, but no joy so far. This worked in Craft 3, but not in Craft 4.

It's a CSS cache buster, I basically want a variable to set in env, then taken into general.php[caveat] and then onto a template.

It seems you cannot have custom variables in Craft 4 in config/general.php. I've created a config/custom.php

// env

```
testtest=123456
```

// config/custom.php

```
'variablestored' => getenv('testtest'),
```

//template

```
{{ craft.app.config.general.variableStored }}
```

Results in an error: Calling unknown method: craft\config\GeneralConfig::variableStored()

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're still trying to access the custom config settings through the general config, this is what's causing the error. Instead of `craft.app.config.general`, use `craft.app.config.custom`:

```twig
{{ craft.app.config.custom.variablestored }}
```

This is covered in the [upgrade guide for Craft 4](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/upgrade.html#configuration).

**Update 2022-06-22:** The [documentation on configuration settings](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/) now mentions [custom settings](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/#custom-config-settings) explicitly, including code examples for accessing custom config values in both Twig and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

As highlighted by @MoritzLost, in Twig, you should be calling `{{ craft.app.config.custom.myVar }}`, not using the GeneralConfig service.

Also worth highlighting, rather than calling getenv() in your custom.php, you can use the App helper, with App::env('testtest').